# Can't cleanly install Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I had a bare-bones install of Visual Studio 2008 on my computer, which I think I picked up from installing SQL Server 2008. I later installed VS2008 Standard edition, but I couldn't create any new projects (I only had like 1 or 2 unusual options under C#). So I uninstalled all of the VS2008 stuff that wasn't the Standard edition, which allowed me to create new projects, but I couldn't debug (probably because one of the things I uninstalled was a debugger).

So I thought I'd start over, fully uninstalling and re-installing VS2008, but doing so gave me a bunch of errors when I tried to start the app, and my WPF XANL designer didn't appear any more (I just got the regular XML editor). So I followed [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/joy/archive/2008/10/21/how-to-remove-visual-studio-2008-manually.aspx) to completely uninstall VS2008, but after doing so and re-installing, I still don't have a WPF XAML editor with a designer.

So clearly I have something sticking around, as I've managed to install this copy of VS2008 Standard before, but I'm not sure what to do to get a clean install.

I'm running Windows 7, and I have VS2010 Beta 2 and SQL Server 2008 (and 2005 express, which I accidentally picked up on my latest VS2008 install) installed as well.

How can I get a clean uninstall and re-install? Or can I get the WPF designer preview back some other way?

**Update**
When I right-click on a .xaml file and select "View code", I get an error message that says:

> Ther is no editor available for ".xaml". Make sure
>   the application for the file type
>   (.xaml) is installed.

It's pretty descriptive of the problem, but I thought it could shed some light.

Comment: Have you tried the repair option in Programs and Features (instead of uninstall)?

Comment: I have. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You would probably get more traction on this question if you asked on superuser.com.  By default, you can always just wipe the machine and start over.  VS registers way too much stuff in the registry to try a manual uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this using below command in VS command prompt

devenv /resetskippkgs

Check if it helps...